# Can Big Data attack RSA by just calculating many prime multiplications in advance?

Tags: rsa, public-key, cryptanalysis, prime-numbers

#### Intro

I am somewhat new to cryptography.

Repeating the basics of RSA from [How are the primes used to generate RSA keys?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2405/how-are-the-primes-used-to-generate-rsa-keys?rq=1):

> Textbooks say the one-way function is merely two primes (with some
> critical constraints) ...

may be a good base of this question, as well as [What prime lengths are used for RSA?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/22971/what-prime-lengths-are-used-for-rsa). Also, [Big data and modern crypto systems](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43157/big-data-and-modern-crypto-systems) already asks the same thing as the question here, but in a more abstract way.

#### The idea

Why not calculating in advance, on many computers, a vast amount of multiplications of primes that you loop over systematically, in the constraints of RSA? And then you would save the outcome as keys in a Big Data system that you can quickly search through? You could use a Bloom filter, a key coordinator or other Big Data tricks to quickly find the computers that might have the multiplied value at hand, and then quickly find a value's underlying primes.

You could have 10000 computers, with chosen different starting prime ranges. The first and second primes could be within a likely range that is needed to meet RSA standards of 4096 bit. You may also guess a bit, meaning to take a range that is rather around the square root of a chosen outcome, or take other tricks to guess a bit.

Then it just depends on how many computers you use. Even if you hit just 0.001 % of the possible combinations you could already get the private key from the public key in 0.001 % of the cases. Or do I oversee something here.

#### The question

It cannot be that easy, can it? Can Big Data attack RSA by just calculating many prime multiplications in advance?